# Permutation question, 9 seats.. 3 nationalities.

Tags: permutations

There are 9 seats in a row, 3 Chinese people.. 3 Russians and 3 Poles.
How many ways are there for those people to be seated, so that they don't sit next to a person of the same nationality.

Would anyone be so kind, so as to tell me if this is the answer?

6*4*2=48

Answer (score 0):

48 is not the answer.

First let's figure out how many options you have for each selection.

The first seat is available for anyone to sit in, so there are 9 possible selections.
The second seat is a little trickier, normally there would be 8 remaining options, but to take into account the 2 remaining people of the  same nationality of the previous seat, we must subtract them from the possible selections for seat number 2....this gives us 6 possibilities. Continue this pattern down to the last seat, and multiply all the options for each seat together to find the answer. The number will be a lot larger than your original answer.

Comment: Appreciated Mike.. would you mind telling me if this is it?  9*6*5*4*4*3*2*2*1?

Comment: That looks right, so 51840 possible permutations....and we aren't dividing by anything since all of the people are being picked. kind of like a "pick 9 out of 9" which would be 9!/0!. Modified to fit the stipulations of this particular question.

Comment: well technically we are dividing by 0!, which is 1 so the answer is 51840/1 = 51840.

Comment: Be careful at the fourth step.  Suppose you have selected a Russian for the first seat and a Chinese for the second seat.  There are five choices for the third seat since there are three Poles and two Russians available.  If you have selected a Pole for the third seat, there are now four choices for the fourth seat - the two remaining Russians and two remaining Chinese.  If you have selected a Russian for the third seat, there are still five choices - the two remaining Chinese and the three Poles.

Comment: Ahh, my answer may be incorrect then. I'm still a novice at this aswell so I'm not quite sure at this point.